# Python Regular Expression to find single letter Cardinal Direction

Tags: python

I have a string with a street name from my hometown (Houston) that looks like this:

- 'FM 517 W'
- 'FM E 42nd'
- 'N Katy Freeway'

I am trying to create a regular expression that finds the single letter cardinal directions (N, S, E or W) and replace them with the full words (North, South, East or West).

This is the code that I've written so far:

```
single_cardinals = re.compile(r'[NnSsEeWw]+(/s)')
```

Unfortunately, it's not picking up any of the strings listed above. The regex works on regexpal.com :(

Thank you for any and all help!
`

Comment: Please show the code where you try to use your regex to search your list of examples. Include the examples, and show the results.

Comment: Your cardinal letter aren’t always followed by a space. Maybe look at the word boundary matching? Also the + is a very blunt instrument because while yes it allows match NE it also allows matching Ss - it’s not hard to enumerate all the possible cardinal points is it? Then refine it if you can.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I believe the "+" was interfering with my bracket search. I don't actually have any NW, NE, etc. characters. Only the 4 basic ones.

I have updated this into 3 problems:
Find the cardinal if it's at the end, at the beginning, or in the middle. This is the code I've produced and it works:

`end = re.compile(r'( |^)[NnSsEeWw]$')`
`middle = re.compile(r'( )[NnSsEeWw]( ))`
`beginning = re.compile(r'(^)[NnSsEeWw]( ))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `\b` word boundary delimiter, see [this doc](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Regexes are pretty cool, so posting here an example for you on how you could put some nice basis to leverage them even better in the future.

In below example, I'm separating the string in 3 matchable parts: `(.*)\b([NnSsEeWw])\b(.*)`

- `(.*)` captures everything it can (note: you can change that to be `(.*?)`, the question mark would make the regex match the smallest possible string instead of the largest possible - this would make it so that the **first** NSEW letter would be found instead of the **last** - you can test that edge case with a fictional address like `FM W 517 W` for example with 2 `W`-s to see which one is matched with both variants)
- `\b` is used as word boundary (meaning: what follows must not be within a word)
- then your `[NnSsEeWw]` is captured
- and finally the remainder of the text in another `(.*)`

```
import re


single_cardinals = re.compile(r"(.*)\b([NnSsEeWw])\b(.*)")
long_cardinals = {"N": "North", "S": "South", "E": "East", "W": "West"}


def expanded_cardinals(text):
    m = single_cardinals.match(text)
    if m:
        short = m.group(2).upper()
        if short in long_cardinals:
            expanded = (m.group(1), long_cardinals[short], m.group(3))
            text = "".join(expanded)

    return text


print(expanded_cardinals("FM 517 W"))
print(expanded_cardinals("FM E 42nd"))
print(expanded_cardinals("N Katy Freeway"))
print(expanded_cardinals("Montgomery"))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for!
Your explanation was beautiful and helped a lot, thank you very much!